# Parsing JSON response using text summarization API, encoding error in response

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I use service at https://www.meaningcloud.com/products/automatic-summarization
for text summarization. I am using .NET Core 5

For example, I want shorten this news: https://e.vnexpress.net/news/business/economy/vn-index-rises-for-third-straight-session-4141865.html

```cs
string input = "..." // long content of news post.
var client = new RestClient("https://api.meaningcloud.com/summarization-1.0");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("key", "25870359b682ec3c93f9becd850eb459");  // fake token because this content is public.        
request.AddParameter("sentences", 4);
request.AddParameter("txt", JsonEncodedText.Encode(content));

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
var res = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
// Need convert \r\n , \r\n\r\n to space.
string short_content = res["summary"].ToString();
// SysUtil.StringEncodingConvert(short_content, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");            
string result = raw_string.Replace(" [...] ", " ");
```

Input

```
The benchmark VN-Index saw steady growth throughout the day, gradually gaining a total of 10.23 points by the end of the session. The Ho Chi Minh Stock Exchange (HoSE), on which the index is based, saw 300 stocks gain and 78 lose. Total trading volume improved 48 percent over the previous session, reaching VND6.2 trillion ($269 million). The VN30-Index, a basket of HoSE’s 30 largest capped stocks, rose 1.63 percent, with 27 gaining and 2 losing. Its top gainers were SAB of Vietnam’s largest brewer Sabeco, up 4.8 percent, followed by VJC of budget airline Vietjet, up 2.8 percent, and MWG of electronics retailer Mobile World, up 2.2 percent. Of Vietnam’s biggest state-owned lenders by assets, BID of BIDV climbed 0.85 percent, VCB of Vietcombank 0.8 percent, and CTG of VietinBank 0.6 percent. HDB of HDBank and TCB of Techcombank led gains of private banks at 0.85 percent and 0.6 percent respectively. Other gainers included PNJ of Phu Nhuan Jewelry with 1.4 percent, HPG of steel producer Hoa Phat, 1.1 percent, and MSN of conglomerate Masan, 1 percent. The only two VN30 tickers that ended in the red were VIC of conglomerate Vingroup, down 1 percent, and PLX of fuel distributor Petrolimex, down 0.05 percent. The HNX-Index for stocks on the Hanoi Stock Exchange, home to mid and small caps, rose 1.35 percent, and the UPCoM-Index for stocks on the Unlisted Public Companies Market added 0.3 percent. Foreign investors turned net buyers to the tune of VND15.7 billion ($681,600), with buying pressure focused mainly on HPG and VHM of real estate giant Vinhomes.
```

output after text summarization (4 sentences)

```
The benchmark VN-Index saw steady growth throughout the day, gradually gaining a total of 10.23 points by the end of the session. The VN30-Index, a basket of HoSE\u2019s 30 largest capped stocks, rose 63 percent, with 27 gaining and 2 losing. Of Vietnam\u2019s biggest state-owned lenders by assets, BID of BIDV climbed 0.85 percent, VCB of Vietcombank 0.8 percent, and CTG of VietinBank 0.6 percent. The HNX-Index for stocks on the Hanoi Stock Exchange, home to mid and small caps, rose 1.35 percent, and the UPCoM-Index for stocks on the Unlisted Public Companies Market added 0.3 percent.
```

[image]

I also try use util

```
using System;

namespace myproj.Controllers
{

    public class SysUtil
    {
        public static String StringEncodingConvert(String strText, String strSrcEncoding, String strDestEncoding)
        {
            System.Text.Encoding srcEnc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(strSrcEncoding);
            System.Text.Encoding destEnc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(strDestEncoding);
            byte[] bData = srcEnc.GetBytes(strText);
            byte[] bResult = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(srcEnc, destEnc, bData);
            return destEnc.GetString(bResult);
        }
    }

}
```

but not success.

even I replace, still not success

```cs
tring result2 = result.Replace("\u2019s", "'s");
```

I catch some problem

`\u2019s` --> I need `'s`, how to archive this?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to the application default encoding format (or the OS default encoding format), because, I try to test the following code `string oriString = "a basket of HoSE\u2019s 30 largest capped stocks"; var result = oriString.Replace("\u2019", "'");` it will directly display the "'s", instead of "\u2019". Try to check it on your side. Besides, please check your code `string short_content = res["summary"].ToString(); string result = raw_string.Replace(" [...] ", " ");`, make sure you are using the correct variable name (short_content and raw_string).

Answer (score 1):

`\u2019` is the unicode char for smart quote. Just replace that:

```
result2 = result.Replace('\u2019', '\'')
```